# trying to reuse a WPF window

Tags: wpf, window, styles

The xaml below is for a Window I am using in several presentations where the only thing that varies is the UserControl that it hosts:

```
    <Window x:Class="Smack.ConstructionAdmin.Presentation.Wpf.Views.Admin.Employees.EmployeeShellView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Smack.ConstructionAdmin.Presentation.Wpf.Views.Admin.Employees" 
        xmlns:s="clr-namespace:Smack.ConstructionAdmin.Presentation.Wpf" 
        xmlns:cmdRef="clr-namespace:Smack.Core.Presentation.Wpf.ViewModels.Commands.Reference;assembly=Smack.Core.Presentation.Wpf" 

        Background="{DynamicResource WaveWindowBackground}"
        Title="{Binding Source={x:Static s:Strings.AppName}}"  
        Icon="pack://application:,,,/Smack.ConstructionAdmin.Presentation.Wpf;component/Images/Time-Machine_16.png"
        FontFamily="Arial"  
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Width="750" Height="600" 
        >
    <DockPanel>
        <local:EmployeeShellUserControl DataContext="{Binding}"  />
    </DockPanel>

    <Window.InputBindings>
        <cmdRef:KeyBindingEx  CommandReference="{Binding AddCommand}"/>
        <cmdRef:KeyBindingEx  CommandReference="{Binding EditCommand}"/>
        <cmdRef:KeyBindingEx  CommandReference="{Binding DeleteCommand}"/>
    </Window.InputBindings>

</Window>
```

So it seems to make sense to reuse the parts that do not vary somehow. Here is my first attempt at doing so with a style:

```
<Style x:Key="MyWindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource WaveWindowBackground}"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="600"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="750"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding AppName}"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{Binding IconUri}"></Setter>
</Style>
```

## Pain points

1. I couldn't find a property setter for WindowStartupLocation
2. I don't see how to make the InputBindings part of the style

IS using a style the right approach or is there some other technique I need to use? How can I set the above properties?

Cheers.
Berryl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you simply create a window of this type without content, and then add the `UserControl` of your choice as its `Content` before showing it? You won't need multiple `Window` subclasses, and you won't need to mess with styles.

A trivial example, where we 're setting the window's content to a string (normally you 'd use some appropriate `UserControl`):

```
var window = new EmployeeShellView();
window.Content = "Hello world!"; // set to your UserControl
window.Show();
```

If you want to insert a complex `UserControl`, say this one:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyControl">
    <DockPanel>
        <local:EmployeeShellUserControl DataContext="{Binding}"  />
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

You would do:

```
var window = new EmployeeShellView();
window.Content = new MyControl();
window.Show();
```

Comment: That sounds perfect! BUT not sure what you mean - could you scratch out some code and / or xaml to illustrate better?

Comment: @Berryl: I 've added an example, does it look OK?

Comment: so leave the ShellView as is, instantiate it and set the Content? How does the part where I replace the existing UserControl become the Content, or is that the definition of the Content property?

Comment: I don't see Content in the docs for a Window. Is that a standard property and I'm missing it or a place holder you are adding? Not getting that part yet

Comment: @Berryl: It's [`ContentControl.Content`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content.aspx) -- `Window` derives from `ContentControl`.

Comment: Oh yeah, cool. I can set the DataContext too then. So the existing UserControl I posted **is** that Window's Content, huh? Too easy, too cool - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to overcome your problems with attached behavior that will be set on the style.

Just Google attached behavior wpf